# How to add links to Google GeoChart maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a custom clickable map using GeoChart from Google for a website. I want countries to be clickable, where once users select different countries on the map, it would direct them to a separate web page. Also,  I want the color to change when it's in a selected state. 
Can someone help me with the JavaScript on how to add the select event?  I would appreciate it.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD3MfRYHAynUsxWCZ8NDsA3cwvWlTkhT1s'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country'],
      ['Thailand' ],
      ['India'],
      ['Malaysia'],
      ['Sri Lanka'],
      ['Indonesia'],
      ['Vietnam'],
      ['Korea'],
      ['Taiwan'],
      ['China'],  
    ]);

    var options = {
      region: '142', // Asia
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#f5f5f5']},
      datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
      defaultColor: '#ff8040',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 700px; height: 433px;">  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in my code you need to add a listener which is the google.visualization.events.addListener. Then inside that listener, you can get the name of the selected country. I printed by console.log() function you can do whatever you like with that.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD3MfRYHAynUsxWCZ8NDsA3cwvWlTkhT1s'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country'],
      ['Thailand' ],
      ['India'],
      ['Malaysia'],
      ['Sri Lanka'],
      ['Indonesia'],
      ['Vietnam'],
      ['Korea'],
      ['Taiwan'],
      ['China'],  
    ]);

    var options = {
      region: '142', // Asia
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#f5f5f5']},
      datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
      defaultColor: '#ff8040',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
      var country = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
      console.log(country);

      
    }    
  });  };
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
  </script>
 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 700px; height: 433px;">  </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```